# Hago un scrape a IMDb y no consigo sacar la información que quiero

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

quiero hacer, una api para aprender un poco sobre beautifulsoup4 y flask, que trata de directamente hacer un scraping de la pagina IMDb, como un ejemplo, y convertirlo en un resultado JSON para poder usarlo facilmente con requests, pero mi codigo, aunque me devuelve una lista con la misma cantidad de peliculas que se muestran en la pagina, me sale vacia el dictionary en vez del nombre de las peliculas

```
# Import Modules
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
# Initialize API
app = Flask(__name__)
# First API Call
@app.route("/api/v1/topmovies")
def topmovies():
  re = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250")
  html_soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
  result = html_soup.find_all('tbody', class_="lister-list")
  he = []
  for i in result:
    for i in i.find_all("tr"):
    element = i.find_all("td", class_="titlecolumn")
    doc = ""
    for i in element:
      for i in i.find("a"):
        doc = i
      he.append({"movieTitle": doc})
  return jsonify(he)
app.run(port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Te refieres a que has hecho print a `he` y si te trae los datos que debería pero al momento del return no los regresa? o en qué momento falla? Has hecho `print` a los `for` para ver si sí está entrando al ciclo?

Comment: devuelve una lista, de caracteres, pero no es lo esperado, ya que lo que devuelve, devuelve [{"movietitle":""}...]

Comment: Revisando el código de la página, tienes un error en el nombre de la clase. La clase se llama `titleColumn` con `camelCase` y tu lo tienes todo en minúsculas `titlecolumn`

Haz este cambio y te traerá todos los nombres.